# show that the series $ \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{z^n}{n^{3/2}}$ converges uniformly for $|z|< 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

> show that the series $ \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{z^n}{n^{3/2}}$ converges uniformly for $|z|< 1$

I don't know how to begin this problem, can someone tell me how can i demonstrate this.

Comment: You would definitely want to start your sum at $n=1$. Also, the keyword 'Weierstrass M-test' would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: For all $|z| \le 1$:

$$\left|\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^{3/2}} \right| \ \le \ \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{|z|^n}{n^{3/2}} \ \le \ \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}.$$

What do we know about $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^a}$ for all constants $a$ at least say 5/4?

Comment: is the p-series right?. Thanks so much, i forgot this

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Writing in the form $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{z^n}{n^{3/2}}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_nz^n,$ we see that $a_n=\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$.

The radius of convergence is given by $R=\frac{1}{\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}}$.

Then, for any $z$ with $|z|\leq r<R$, the series will converge uniformly.

Comment: this is an interesting solution for the problem i think, I was just studying the convergence radio part, thank you very much for this.

Comment: This line of reasoning is insufficient though. The sum would not converge uniformly on $|z|  < 1$ iff the denominator were $n$ instead of $n^{3/2}$, even though $R$ is still 1. This series would convergr uniformly on $|z| < a$ for any $a<1$ but that is a weaker statement...

Comment: There's nothing I said that was incorrect, but yes, there is a stronger statement for this particular problem.